# Does JAXB uses SAX or DOM internally?

Tags: xml, jaxb

I could not find answer for this question , could anybody please let me know

Since JAXB is an higher level API , does JAXB uses SAX or DOM internally ?

Comment: As Blaise points out, JAXB is an interface, not an implementation. You'll have to ask your question in relation to a specific implementation.

Comment: So maybe a better question would be what parser does the reference JAXB implementation use (the one in the JDK since Java 1.6)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Note**:  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Individual JAXB (JSR-222) implementations are free to choose the underlying parsing technologies they use for different inputs.  The strategy we use in MOXy is to use StAX ([**javax.xml.stream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html)) as much as possible.

There are ways to control what parser your JAXB impl uses.  Below is a link to an answer I gave explaining how to get a JAXB impl to use a specific SAX parser:

- [How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909465/how-to-disable-dtd-fetching-using-jaxb2-0/9910012#9910012)

And another answer explaining how to ensure that StAX is used:

- [Make JAXB go faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626153/make-jaxb-go-faster/8626388#8626388)